# Mongoose not creating MongoDB Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a database using mongoose in my node app but when I use the show databases command in the mongo shell, the database that should be created does not show up, even though the node app runs without any errors

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connecting to the database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');
//checking for errors in connection
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
});
```

This is the code from the app.
I'm trying to create the myapp database but it does not seem to be working, even though the Database connected message appears on the console. The database does not show up in the Mongo shell when I run 'show databases'.

I also have the code that creates a collection schema in another file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const nomineeSchema = new Schema({
    id:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    }
})


module.exports.Nominees = mongoose.model('Nominees', nomineeSchema);
```

The database and the collection does not get created.

This exact same code used to work for another app that I created just a few months back but now it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Try saving a document, everything may get created on saving.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB driver by default do not create empty database and collection. It is created when first document is added.